# Why the metod add in list<T> modify all the elements of the list?

Tags: c#, list

I am making a list of elements, but each time it iterates modify all the elements of the list

I am executing the code step by step and i added and inspection, then i realized that the data that i am retreiving is ok, but when i add an "element" to the list, it modifies all the existents elements

I have this class

```
public class AREntity
{
    public DateTime? FI { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FS { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code that i am executing ....

```
        List<AREntity> list = new List<AREntity>();
        MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection();
        Conn.ConnectionString = sqlCnn;
        Conn.Open();
        try
        {

            String CSql = "LAR";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(CSql, Conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            MySqlDataReader drAR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            AREntity ARE = new AREntity();
            while (drAR.Read())
            {
                ARE.FI = drAR.GetValue(2);
                ARE.FS = drAR.GetValue(3);
                list.Add(ARE);
            }
```

when the code executes

```
                list.Add(ARE);
```

the entire list change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding the same `AREntity` instance to the list and just changing its values. Move the object creation inside the loop:

```
while (drAR.Read())
{
    AREntity ARE = new AREntity();
    ARE.FI = drAR.GetValue(2);
    ARE.FS = drAR.GetValue(3);
    list.Add(ARE);
}
```